# MySQL Interface Error, how do I fix this?

Tags: python, mysql, sql, ssl

I am using mysql to connect to a sql database, and when I run the following code:

```
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(f'mysql+mysqlconnector://{user}:{password}@{server}:{port}/{schema}', echo=False)
```

I receive back the following error:

```
    InterfaceError: (mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError) sha256_password requires SSL
    (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/14/rvf5)
```

Does anyone have any advice on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

The message tells you that the user uses the new athentification method that is not yet supported

Change the user to a legacy password and then you can connect

For that you must run following comand, of course adapted to your configuration

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY '<password>';
```